# Why constraints does not work in Testcontainers?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, testcontainers

I am trying to use testcontainers in my spring boot app.
I also use liquibase and i have simple code there:

```
create table calendar
(
    date date primary key,
    is_weekend boolean not null,
    is_pre_holiday boolean not null,
    check( not (is_weekend and is_pre_holiday) )
);
```

I want to check constraints in my integration tests, please help me if I do something wrong

Here my hibernate entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar")
public class CalendarEntity {
    @Id
    LocalDate date;
    boolean isWeekend;
    boolean isPreHoliday;
}
```

application-integration-test.yaml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql://localhost/testDB
    username: user
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master-test.yaml
    enabled: true
```

So simple test to get calendar from db works fine, but this does not work correctly, it does not trow exception or return null:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class CalendarRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    CalendarRepository calendarRepository;

    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres= new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password")
            .withDatabaseName("test_db");

    @Test
    void dateCanNotBeWeekendAndPreHolidayTest() {
        CalendarEntity calendarEntity = new CalendarEntity(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1), true, true);

        CalendarEntity savedEntity = calendarRepository.save(calendarEntity);
        assertEquals(calendarEntity, savedEntity);
        //they are equal and test is passed, but it shouldn't
    }
```

P.S.

spring-boot 3.0.2

testcontainers 1.17.6

Expect something like this:

ERROR:  new row for relation "calendar" violates check constraint "calendar_check"

Comment: have you tried to call `calendarRepository.saveAndFlush` instead of `calendarRepository.save` or issue `calendarRepository.flush` after `calendarRepository.save` call?

Comment: hmm, i don't try it because that is not what my question is.
My question is about test postgres check constraint on insert operation.

Comment: The real question is: are you sure repository.save does insert data into DB or it can postpone that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrey B. Panfilov, I found that was problem in my code:
I should use saveAndFlush in my test

If we go to SimpleJpaRepository class, which is the implementation of JpaRepository we will find:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

method save returns entity, that was given to that method

And method saveAndFlush in test throws exception, as I expected:

```
2023-03-02T09:37:01.337+05:00 ERROR 6304 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: new row for relation "calendar" violates check constraint "calendar_check"
  Подробности: Failing row contains (2000-01-01, t, t).
```